# Finding a new fan

Tags: fan

this might be a bit unorthodox for this forum, but I hope you can help me anyways.

My friend has a small home server machine.. and the fan in it just broke.. this one:
[Specs on Broken fan](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-Shipping-For-AVC-BNTA0613R2H-Server-Blower-Fan-DC-12V-0-24A-60x60x13mm-3-wire-3/714570800.html)
Now he wants a new one ofcourse, but I'm not sure if he needs to buy that exact one?
or he could simply buy one with same specs?

[This is the computer it was inside](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16856167043)

if someone had the time I would appreciate it if someone could find one that would work as a replacement..
The one I linke to I believe is 'used' and costs 50$ and I dont really like the site I'm looking at.

Comment: Sorry, Allan, but we're technically not a forum, and per our [FAQ] we cannot give you shopping recommendations for specific products. And I guess there's no reason a replacement with the same specs wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Is this a case fan? Any fan with the same dimensions will work, it's only used for air flow. If it's the same size, the screw holes will be in the same place. I can't recommend a product as it's against forum rules, but you'll find different fans are different speeds, some loud, some quiet, some with LED lighting, some without. You wont really know on the noise until you've installed it.

Comment: http://www.ebay.com/itm/MSI-MS-6668-D510-nettop-CPU-heatsink-fan-/130337054088

This is exactly what I need, right prize, its the right one..
its never been used.. but they don't ship to Europe and I live in Denmark :(...